# SQL Update Only when Max Date reached

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've two tables like:

Table1

```
-----------------------------------------
TID1     Name      Status        LastStatus         
-----------------------------------------
1        A         1             3
```

Table2

```
-----------------------------------------
TID2     TID1     oDate          Status
-----------------------------------------
1        1        2020-04-01     1
2        1        2020-04-03     2
3        1        2020-04-05     3
```

The scenario is: If I update the `Table2` on `TID2 = 2`, the `LastStatus` on `Table1` shouldn't be updated because there's a MAX Date on `Table2` with `TID1=1`. So `LastStatus` on `Table1` will only updated if there's an update on `Table2` with MAX Date.

Currently, I only work on `Table2`. It doesn't effect to `Table1`. Below are my code:

```
-- Insert Statement
Declare @TID1 int, @oDate DateTime, @Status int;
Set @TID1 = 1;
Set @oDate = '2020-04-05';
Set @Status = 3;
Insert into Table2 (TID1, oDate, Status) values (@TID1, @oDate, @Status)

-- Update Statement (Example only - if there's a row to be updated)
Update Table2 Set TID1=@TID1, oDate=@oDate, Status=@Status
where TID2 = 3
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: There are 2 actions. Insert and Edit. Insert when there's a new data. Edit if there's a typo when selecting the status or change the date. Based on the requirement. Modified column only date and status.

Comment: Updating the Table2 will trigger update on Table1. But, Update on Table1 if the Date is MAX group by `TID1`

Comment: right now I only insert and update on `Table2`. Doesn't effect to Table1. And this is my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would combine the inserts/updates to both tables in a stored procedure where you would do something like the following:

```
-- Insert into Table2
insert into dbo.Table2 (TIDI1, oDate, [Status])
  select @TIDI1, @oDate, @Status;

-- OR

-- Update Table2
update dbo.Table2 set
  TID1 = @TIDI1
  , oDate = @oDate
  , [Status] = @Status
where TID2 = @TID2;

-- Then update table1 if the date we just added is the latest or more recent
update dbo.Table1 set
  LastStatus = @Status
where TID1 = @TIDI1
and @oDate >= (select max(oDate) from dbo.Table2 T2 where T2.TID1 = @TID1);

if @@rowcount = 0 print 'Do nothing';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found my answer.. Thank you so much for answering my question.

```
update      ActivityPlanHistory
    set         ActivityPlanId = ActivityPlanId, UpdateDate = @UpdateDate, 
                StatusId = @StatusId, Remarks = @Remarks
    where       ActivityPlanHistoryId = @ActivityPlanHistoryId;

    if (select max(UpdateDate) from ActivityPlanHistory where ActivityPlanId = @ActivityPlanId) <= @UpdateDate
        begin 
            update      ActivityPlan 
            set         LastStatus = @StatusId, LastUpdateDate = @UpdateDate, 
                        LastRemarks = @Remarks
            where       ActivityPlanId = @ActivityPlanId
        end
    else
        begin
            print 'do nothing';
        end
```

Comment: So *best practice* when writing T-SQL is to keep all operations set based, not structured (IF/ELSE/END) like you have done. I have shown in my answer how to keep it set-based.